# Typescript: Using boolean type is not accepted by TS compiler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Right now, I put `isLoading` to `any`, but if I put it to `boolean` (like I want it to be), it throws the following error when hovering over the "Loading" const. As far as I understand, this should be working. Very new to Typescript, so please be gentle. Any help would be appreciated.

**package.json**

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-router": "^5.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"typescript": "^4.0.3"
```

**Error message**

```
Type '{ ({ isLoading, size, color, }: LoadingProps): false | JSX.Element; defaultProps: Partial<LoadingProps> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'FC<LoadingProps>'.
  Type 'false | Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
    Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.ts(2322)
```

**index.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ClipLoader from 'react-spinners/ClipLoader';

interface LoadingProps {
  isLoading: any;
  size?: number;
  color?: string;
}

/**
 * Loading icon to let user know a promise is going on
 *
 * @param isLoading Passing true to show spinner, and pass false to remove it
 * @param size react-spinner parameter for size of icon
 * @param color Color of Loading icon
 */

const Loading: React.FC<LoadingProps> = ({
  isLoading,
  size = 35,
  color = '#F6F7FB',
}: LoadingProps) => {
  return isLoading && <ClipLoader size={size} color={color} />;
};

Loading.defaultProps = {
  size: 35,
  color: '#F6F7FB',
};

export default Loading;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `isLoading` is `false` your return statement returns `false`, which is not a `ReactElement`.

I'd suggest always using a ternary for conditional rendering instead. Like:

```
return isLoading ? <ClipLoader size={size} color={color} /> : null
```

See [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) in docs for more details.

Comment: +1 This fixed it. I didn't think about if it was false. I did the `null` return and it made everything better. Thank you so much! Will mark as the accepted answer.